# How to select this element by its string of CSS selectors?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

From this [url](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimer), I'm trying to extract the link `https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/conjugation/aimer` in

```
<a class="link-right verbtable" href="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/conjugation/aimer">Full verb table</a>
```

whose CSS selector is `div.content.definitions.dictionary.biling > div.hom > span > span.xr > a`. I follow the instruction from the book *Automate the Boring Stuff with Python* as

[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimer'
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

soup.select('div.content.definitions.dictionary.biling > div.hom > span > span.xr > a')
```

Could you please elaborate on how the result is `[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Collins Dictionary uses Cloudfare to increase the security and performance of their web sites and services. So when you requests to its server. It won't give you the HTML file.

```
<title>Access denied | www.collinsdictionary.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
```

In order to pass its security. You have to set a user agent in requests.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

user_agent = {'User-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"}

url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimer'
doc = requests.get(url, headers = user_agent).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')
result = soup.select('div.content.definitions.dictionary.biling > div.hom > span > span.xr > a')
print(result)
```

This will gives you the result:

```
[<a class="link-right verbtable" href="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/conjugation/aimer">Full verb table</a>]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought that `user_agent` is not so important :(. Is it possible to modify `result = soup.select('div.content.definitions.dictionary.biling > div.hom > span > span.xr > a')` to get the value after `href=`?

Comment: By getting the href value you have to use: `link = result[0].attrs["href"]`. This will get the href value.